# Possible git bug (`git checkout` failure)

Tags: git

This is the closest I can come a minimal example.  (Granted, the example is weird, but that's par-for-the-course for minimal examples.)

Run the following script in some suitable scratch directory (e.g. `/tmp).  The script will create a directory`demo`, and initialize a repo in it.  It will then create *two entirely distinct branches, having *nothing* in common.*  These branches are populated from content coming out of two GitHub repos.

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -rf demo
mkdir demo
cd demo
git init
git commit -m 'root commit' --allow-empty

for URL in https://github.com/octocat/Spoon-Knife \
           https://github.com/octocat/hello-worId
do
    rm -rf content

    basename=$(basename $URL)
    branch_name=${basename%.git}
    git branch $branch_name
    git checkout $branch_name
    git clone $URL content
    rm -rf content/.git
    git add content
    git commit -m $branch_name
    git checkout master
done

git branch -a
git checkout Spoon-Knife
```

At the end of this script, the current branch is `Spoon-Knife`.  If one now issues the command `git checkout hello-world`, `git` fails with the error:

```
error: pathspec 'hello-world' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Is this valid behavior?

Comment: Those are two separate *repositories*, not branches. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Somebody's yanking your chain.  octocat has "Hello-World" and "hello-worId" repos.  Check those names in a programmer's font.  The one used here on SO will do. Look closely.

Comment: @jthill: thanks, that was it.  I missed that completely.  (And got downvoted for it, to boot.)

Comment: @ceejayouz: wrong.  The problem was that I missed the fact that GitHub chose to use an upper-case "I" in place of a lower-case "l".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created the branch `hello-worid` but tried to checkout `hello-worLd`?

Not sure why you would name your repo like that and confuse yourself...

Comment: It's the other way around (the branch I created is `hello-worId`, but the one I tried to checkout is `hello-world`), but I see the problem now.  BTW, I did not choose the confusing names.  GitHub did.  Why did they do that on repos ostensibly designed to teach beginners about git and GitHub?  That's a good question.

Comment: That's what i said...
Anyway, on command-line use the tab key to auto-complete long names and avoid spelling mistakes ;)